# Arrays counting

Tags: java, arrays, loops, counting

If my program gives the user about a team's championship history, for example, if the user enters Chelsea, my program will say, "They have won it in 2012,2010,2007,2008" (using parallel array list already provided and has to be used). 
How would i display, from that result, the number of times they have won . So if that information is correct, i want my program to say, "Chelsea has won it 4 times".

This is what i have so far:

```
public static void showWinner(short years[], String winners[]){
    Scanner kd = new Scanner (System.in);
    String name;
    System.out.println("Which teams result would you like to see?: " );
    name = kd.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {
        if (winners[i].equals(name)){
             System.out.println(years[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what you're asking is how to keep a count and increment it every time you find a year they won in?

Comment: Really, you should figure this out by yourself.

Comment: yes thats it, i know how to sum up array values but i have no idea how to count @chris

Comment: @JBNizet. I am only starting out at java, not all of us have a natural knack for this kind of stuff.

Comment: my mistake I understood your winners/years logic wrong. Anyway just keep a counter and increase it when a match is found

Comment: What is the association between winners array and years array ?

Comment: Your code shows that you already learned what int variables are, how you increment an int variable, how to implement a test, and how you print something to the screen. COmbine all these, and you'll find the solution.

Comment: Why don't you use a Map instead of parallel lists ?

Comment: @noob this is an assignment for uni, we have to use the parallel lists provided, cant even use classes.

Comment: @noob years array gives us the years and the winners array corresponds to the years with the winning team for that particular year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: I am assuming that winners array and years array has mapping in which year which team won. I suggest you to use Map for this purpose. It will be more understandable and efficient.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < winners.length; i++){
    if (winners[i].equals(name)){
        count ++;
        System.out.println(years[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println(name + " has won it" + count + "times");
```

Comment: Which teams result would you like to see?: 
Wests
1930
Wests has won it 1 times
1934
Wests has won it 1 times
1948
Wests has won it 1 times
1952
Wests has won it 1 times
2005
Wests has won it 1 times @Achintya Jha i get that output

Comment: @user2278109 You have placed the code inside your existing for-loop. Remove the for-loop entirely and replace it with this code.

Comment: @user2278109 then you've not copy'n pasted the above code correctly. Try understanding what the code does.

Comment: thanks for all your help guys @ArnoSluismans, it took me a while to understand the code pasted above. I have it working. Thanks.

Comment: @user2278109 Why you unaccept my answer ? I dont see any difference between my code and noob code. Its like copy and paste my code.

Comment: @AchintyaJha i didnt? i did use your code, im new to this site, i dont know how half these things work